# Why are .dynsym entries in ELF64 executable uninitialized?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, executable, reverse-engineering

I have an `x86-64` executable and I am trying to analyze it using static methods. Starting from `_start`, I see a jump to `0x400648` - an address within the `PLT` - which contains the instruction `jmp *0x20065a(%rip)`. This jump leads to `*0x600ca8`, which is actually `0x40064e`. This brings us back to the `PLT` and executes `pushq $0x2`.

Here's where I'm stuck: I know the `pushq $0x2` instruction exists to tell the dynamic linker to resolve the 3rd entry in the `.dynsym` table. The problem is that the `st_value` field in that entry is `0x0`. This value should actually be the offset of `main` from `_start`, right? If so, how does the `st_value` field get initialized?

Answer (score 1):

> This value should actually be the offset of main from _start, right?

Wrong. You can't just jump from `_start` to `main` -- the latter expects `argc` and `argv[]` parameters, but nobody has them set up yet. It is the job of `libc` initialization code to:

- initialize libc itself, create standard `FILE` handles (`stdout`, etc.), set up the environment, etc. and
- call `main` with correct arguments, and
- if/when `main` returns, arrange for the program to `exit(2)` with correct exit code.

What you are seeing is actually a `PLT` call to `__libc_start_main`, which will do all of the above, and *then* call `main`. You can see this with `objdump -dr a.out`, which will look similar to this:

```
00000000004003d0 <_start>:
  4003d0:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  4003d2:       49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  4003d5:       5e                      pop    %rsi
  4003d6:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  4003d9:       48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  4003dd:       50                      push   %rax
  4003de:       54                      push   %rsp
  4003df:       49 c7 c0 50 05 40 00    mov    $0x400550,%r8
  4003e6:       48 c7 c1 c0 04 40 00    mov    $0x4004c0,%rcx
  4003ed:       48 c7 c7 b4 04 40 00    mov    $0x4004b4,%rdi
  4003f4:       e8 c7 ff ff ff          callq  4003c0 <__libc_start_main@plt>
  4003f9:       f4                      hlt
  4003fa:       90                      nop
  4003fb:       90                      nop
```

> how does the st_value field get initialized?

You can read about the actual details of how dynamic symbol resolution works [here](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf) (search for "Procedure Linkage Table"; be warned: few people actually understand how this works in detail).

Comment: Is there any way to statically determine what the address of `main` will be?